# How to control UIPage ViewController transition speed?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipageviewcontroller

i m using UIPageViewController with page curl transition.How can i control transition page speed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom animation i think something like,

```
   let animation: CATransition = CATransition()
    animation.delegate = self
    animation.duration = 1.0
    animation.startProgress = 0.2
    animation.endProgress = 1
    animation.type = "pageCurl"
    animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards
    self.view.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "animation")
```